# Display popup modal dialogue /popup onclicking the row in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have a data table which is being rendered using `DT:: rendertableOutput` in my shiny dashboard. The Columns are `A`, `B`,`C`,`D`. Now I would like to display only column `A` and `B` on opening the Shiny app and later If I click on the particular row on the displayed datatable I need to bring out a pop up which displays data in same row in the column `C` and `D`.

Below is my data frame:

```
> df
   A         B       C      D
   A1        B1      C1     D1
   A2        B2      C2     D2
```

**Conditions:**

1. On opening of the shiny app, only column `A` and `B` are displayed.
2. When `row 1` of the displayed data is clicked then `row 1` of column `C` and `D` are displayed as a popup which has `close` button. And this continue similarly when other row are displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try adding this to the server code. Essentially, we're triggering a modal dialog box to appear when you select a particular row, and to display the rest of the data.

```
require(dplyr)

#Here's our table:
tbl <- data.frame(A= c('A1','A2'),
           B= c('B1','B2'),
           C = c('C1','C2'),
           D = c('D1','D2'))

#The dt output code
output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
       datatable(tbl %>% select(A,B),selection='single')
})

#reactive table based on the selected row 
tbl_reactive <- reactive({
       tbl[as.numeric(input$my_table_rows_selected[1]),]
})

#here's the table displayed in our modal
output$modal_table <- renderDataTable({
      tbl_reactive()
})

 #our modal dialog box
    myModal <- function(failed=FALSE){
       modalDialog(
  dataTableOutput('modal_table'),
         easyClose = TRUE

       )
     }

#event to trigger the modal box to appear
 observeEvent(input$my_table_rows_selected,{

   showModal(myModal())

 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!! The code works partially, Like I am able to view only `col A ` and `col B` on start opening of the app and onclick a pop up appears. All these are working exactly as I wanted it to. But inside the popup there is no data of `col C` and `col D` . Any libraries that I need to call ?

Comment: Thank, Its working fine The issues was there was a unwanted space in `dataTableOutput('modal_table')`.